# Turning one row into a boolean variable in SQL (Snowflake)`

Tags: sql, binary, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So let's say I have some data as follows:

```
value      value2     ID 
hamburger      34     1001
hotdog         04     1001
pizza          12     1001
hamburger      13     1002
hotdog         32     1002
pizza          32     1002
frenchfry      43     1002
watermelon     01     1002
watermelon    222     1003  
hamburger     111     1003
```

I care about watermelon. So I want to know which users provided `watermelon` as a response; I have a specific format I need but here is what I am looking for.

```
value      value2     ID    watermelon_user
hamburger      34     1001            FALSE
hotdog         04     1001            FALSE
pizza          12     1001            FALSE
hamburger      13     1002             TRUE
hotdog         32     1002             TRUE
pizza          32     1002             TRUE
frenchfry      43     1002             TRUE
watermelon     01     1002             TRUE
watermelon    222     1003             TRUE
hamburger     111     1003             TRUE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a window function.  One method is:

```
select t.*,
       count_if(value = 'Watermelon) over (partition by id) > 0 as watermelon_flag
from t;
```

Or `boolor_agg()`:

```
select t.*,
       boolor_agg(value = 'Watermelon) over (partition by id) as watermelon_flag
from t;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `MAX()` window function:

```
SELECT *, MAX(value = 'watermelon') OVER (PARTITION BY ID) watermelon_user
FROM tablename
```